# Can't open symlinks within Samba share

Tags: samba, smb

I have a Samba share on Win Server (I have **no access** to the server settings) with many symlinks in it and a PC with Linux (Ubuntu), from which I try to access the share (I mount it via mount.cifs). But when I try to open a folder which appears to be a symlink, I get access denied.

So, here is my question: Is there any way to access these folders **without** changing samba server settings?

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate. 1) in this case I have Win server and Linux workstation, while in linked question there is Linux server and Windows workstation. 2) In the linked question there is access to server settings, while I do not have such permissions.